# Why is Laravel or Beanstalkd skipping jobs?

Tags: php, laravel, supervisord, beanstalkd

I'm managing audio conversions with **Laravel Queues** and **beanstalkd**, monitored by **supervisord**.

When a user upload an audio file, it goes to `AudioController.php` that triggers a `Queue::push('AudioProcess')`, that itself triggers an `exec('sh some_script.sh some_audio.mp3')` to process the audio and set the application Audio model status to `1` when it's done.

I did a bunch of uploads to test, here are the records
[image: Audio upload records]

`1` means the `AudioProcess.php` worker has been executed and `0` means the `AudioProcess.php` worker hasn't been executed.

I guess it might come from either Laravel Queues management or beanstalkd, but I can't find anything relevant in the logs (`laravel.log`, my supervisord `queue.log`, `php_errors.log`).

I'm running a staging and a production environment on the same server, so there are two Laravel applications and therefore two `php artisan queue:listen` commands running at the same time (each with `--env` specified), if it has something to do with my issue. It worked well few weeks ago, then I dropped the project for a while and recaught it lately. I did some `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` too.

Why is Laravel or beanstalkd not processing all jobs?

Comment: How did you setup your supervisor, share some code, is that running at all?

Comment: supervisord is running with the right configuration loaded, and the daemons it should be running (`php artisan queue:listen --env=[...]` for `staging` and `production`) are running. The problem comes from either Laravel Queues or beanstalkd that don't work all the jobs. I any case it's useful to you, here are the [supervisord main configuration](http://pastebin.com/WR3qgQFb) and the [staging configuration](http://pastebin.com/EY79WLQP).

Comment: Also, [here is a dump](http://pastebin.com/5ZpAr094) of a `ps afx` concerning `supervisord` and `php`.

Comment: I didn't find any `[program]` section in your `supervisor config file`. Also, did you add the process using `add <process_name>` command from terminal/command prompt?

Comment: See the staging configuration (second link). Yes it has been added correctly and is running as you can see in the `ps afx` dump.

Comment: Try to run the job manually from command prompt/terminal using `queue:work` after you add it to the queue and observe the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was likely happening because the two `php artisan queue:listen` (for each environment) were sending jobs to the same beanstalkd queue (`default`). It resulted in some kind of conflict, but I can't tell more...

I fixed it by making each environment's `php artisan queue:listen` send jobs to a `[environment]` queue. Therefore I have now two queues, `staging` and `production`.

**How to do it**

- Create a `app/config/[environment]/queue.php` that overwrites the
  `[connections => [beanstalkd => [queue]]]` parameter from `default`
  to the name of that environment.
- Specify the name of the queue to
  Artisan: `php artisan queue:listen --queue=[environment]`

Comment: Thanks, was loosing my mind with this! I had three sites on the same server and jobs were getting picked up by the wrong queues