# How to run different Beanstalkd Laravel queues from the same server?

Tags: laravel, supervisord, beanstalkd, laravel-queue

I have two different Laravel queues in the same server. In my Supervisord.d folder I have two ini files for those queues. The job names are different in the queues. But, every time I run a job and expect the result from one queue, other queue also interferes. Here is the sample of the ini files:

```
[program:queue_runner]
command = php /path_to_prod/artisan queue:work --daemon --queue=default,smsInt,smsIntLow --tries=1 --timeout=30
stdout_logfile = /path_to_prod/storage/logs/supervisor.log
redirect_stderr = true
numprocs = 5
process_name = %(program_name)s%(process_num)s


[program:queue_runner_test]
command = php /path_to_test/artisan queue:work --daemon --queue=default,smsIntTest,smsIntTestLow --tries=1 --timeout=30
stdout_logfile = /path_to_test/storage/logs/supervisor.log
redirect_stderr = true
numprocs = 50
process_name = %(program_name)s%(process_num)s
```

Could you please help me to solve it.

Comment: Try to use only a queue per worker plz

Comment: Elaborate _"other queue also interferes"_, please

Comment: For the first job I'm using "smsInt,smsIntLow" these two queues and for the second one "smsIntTest,smsIntTestLow" these are the queues. Should I remove default from those? @dparoli

Comment: yes, I have 5 workers in a site, each has only one queue. Try to remove also default.

Comment: Other queues also interfere means, SmsInt and SmsIntLow are chained for queue_runner program and SmsIntTest and SmsInTesttLow are chained together for the queue_runner_test program. For the "queue_runner" job, smsInt -> smsIntTest are executing instead of smsInt->smsIntLow.

Comment: Tried your suggestion @dparoli. But, couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution of my problem. Though the jobs were despatching from the test site on the smsIntTest and from the other site on the smsInt queues from the beginning. But, they were getting picked up by wrong queues every time.

As the following post suggested, [Why is Laravel or Beanstalkd skipping jobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26834623/why-is-laravel-or-beanstalkd-skipping-jobs?rq=1)

I've assigned 'queue' => 'smsInt' in the 'connections' array of the app/config/queue.php file for one site, and 'queue' => 'smsIntTest' for the other one. This solution solved the problem.